# How should Jesus' former existence (before Abraham) be classified?

Tags: john, jesus, abraham, 2-peter, jude

Jesus said 'Before Abraham was I am', John 8:58, immediately after which his hearers took up stones to cast at him, since they clearly regarded this as a blasphemy for only Deity could speak such a thing, *but could not an angel ?*

They took up stones again, later, when he said 'I and the Father are one', John 10:30, for again they counted this as a blasphemy which he clearly shows is not the case for he proves, from scripture, John 10:34, that those to whom the word of God comes, are 'partakers of the divine nature', 2 Peter 1:4 (in justified righteousness and sonship), and are as the Father is, who begat them.

But such as Jesus speaks of, to whom the word of God comes, are in humanity when the word comes to them, but what of He, himself, prior to his incarnation and prior to the existence of Abraham ?

Jude says quite explicitly, that angels who kept not their first estate, Jude 1:6, and who left that state are condemned and confined in everlasting chains until the day of judgment. This clearly relates to the 'sons of God' who saw the daughters of men and left their proper place and state that they might, improperly, partake of humanity and the human condition.

Thus no angel may leave such a proper place and condition and be manifested, permanently (not merely adopting an appearance just to convey a message but taking up a  permanence) without absolute condemnation and removal.

Thus Jesus, prior to incarnation and previous to Abraham's existence, was not in a human condition nor could he have been an angel.

Then in what existence did he exist 'before Abraham was' ?

How are we to classify this existence ?

Comment: Based on your presumption of what ‘before’ means, what hermeneutical quality do you expect of the answers?

Comment: @steveowen I have come to expect a very high quality of hermeneutics from this site and I hope that such will be offered to this question. πρiν - 14 occurrences (Young) as in 'before the cock crow/before they came together' : Meaning 2 'time preceding' [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/17055?redirectedFrom=before#eid).

Comment: "*for only Deity could speak such a thing, but could not an angel?*".  "I am" is a form of the name of God. Why could an angel use this name in that way?

Comment: @RayButterworth I would like to see a full answer on that basis, if that is what you think.

Comment: Sorry, but this looks like a systematic theology question, rather than an exegetical question focused on one particular passage.

Comment: @curiousdannii  The question requires exegesis, particularly with regard to the Greek grammar involved, which also involves a look at the Hebrew for the phrase in question. I am about to post my answer and trust you will see in it requirements that fit the criteria here. It's not the question that is the problem, but possible answers that might stray into systematic theology.

Comment: @Anne I have no doubt that you'd write a good answer, but the question really does need to be focussed in on one particular passage. Four passages are cited here, with pretty much equal emphasis. If a theological synthesis answer is desired then the question should be asked at [christianity.se].

Comment: I'd agree with dannii on the point about doing hermeneutics vs doing theology and that as-is were verging towards theological synthesis - but would suggest that rather than anchoring it on one passage I'd anchor it on John as a whole text, which would allow you to wrap up John 1, 8, 10 and any other related passages and ask how this idea is treated in the text of John. Would that be any help Nigel?

Comment: @SteveTaylor I intend to come at the passage in an entirely different way, but in a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes to say, "I am before you" can mean, 'I am superior to you,' - higher in rank.

Sometimes to say, "I am before you" can mean, 'I am to be served before you,' - as in position in a queue.

Sometimes to say, "I am before you," can mean being born before another person was born.

An example of the latter would be a pair of twins being asked, "Which of you was before the other?" The affirmative answer of the first-born twin would identify the one who came before the other, usually minutes or an hour or so in advance of their twin.

What Jesus said in John 8:58, however, not only has Jesus claiming existing before Abraham came into existence, but goes beyond that to identify himself with the uncreated God in a way that no other human, and no angel, ever has. This is indicated by the extraordinary grammar Jesus employed.

In John 8:58 it is *Ego Eimi* that is translated, 'I Am', and it is simply present tense. If it had been past tense, it would require translation into, 'I have been', in which case the whole sentence would have read, "Before Abraham was, I have been." The extraordinary aspect of what Jesus actually said lies in the fact that he switched tenses half-way through his sentence! He employed past tense for Abraham (who was long dead), then employed present tense for himself - "I am". That is why his use of that phrase here clearly shows it is a form of the name of God, which he applies to himself.

With regard to *ego eimi* being present tense, consider this quote:

> "Undoubtedly, here Jesus claims eternal existence with the absolute
> phrase used of God" (A. T. Robertson, *Word Pictures in the New
> Testament*, Vol. 5 pp 158-159).

Jesus was identifying himself with the God of the Old Testament at Exodus 3:14. If a person doing that *doesn't* mean they are actually claiming to be God, then you could do it too, and so could I. We could call yourselves "ego eimi" in the sense of identifying ourselves with the God of the Hebrews. Indeed, any human being who loves God and lives for God could identify themselves closely with God by saying, "Ego eimi too!" Or is it not the case that nobody would dare claim to be as closely linked to God as did Jesus when he used the "ego eimi" phrase?

Had Jesus *only* been identifying himself with the God of the OT, they would never have been incensed with rage. So, what does the phrase in Exodus 3:14 reveal about Jesus' use of it that so enraged his listeners? Ancient Hebrew words are often difficult to translate into English, and the OT is full of instances of alternative readings for more obscure Hebrew. There are a variety of ways the "I Am" of Exodus 3:14 could be rendered. The NLT says, "I Am Who I Am. Say this to the people of Israel, 'I Am has sent me to you.' God also said to Moses, 'Say this to the people of Israel; Yahweh, the God of our ancestors, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has sent me to you. This is my eternal name, my name to remember for all generations." The footnote adds,

> "This name could also be translated 'I Will Be What I Will Be'. It
> speaks of God who is self-sufficient, self-existent, all encompassing
> and without limitations, the one being in the universe who is not
> dependent on something else for his existence. 'Yahweh' is a
> transliteration of the proper name YHWH. This name is probably a form
> of the Hebrew verb 'to be' so it could mean 'he causes to be', or 'he
> who is', or 'I am'."

When Jesus claimed, "Before Abraham was, I Am", he was identifying himself as not being dependent on something else for his existence. That claim is exclusive to the creator of all life, and both Jesus and his audience knew that.

When the statements Jesus made in verses 23-24 are taken into account, then we see why his claim in verse 58 was so explosive. That's why the Jews were infuriated to the point of trying to stone him. They knew ***Jesus was claiming much, much more than merely identifying himself with the God of the old testament!***

Sorting out different views about Hebrew and Greek grammar is vital, but we have to consider the whole dialogue to realise what Jesus was leading up to in verse 58, for his claim was more massive than any human, or any angel, had ever claimed before. However, that takes us into the realms of systematic theology, so I will not do that. It is sufficient to grasp the Hebrew and Greek behind "I Am" / "Ego eimi" to answer this question.

**Conclusion:** *In what existence did he exist 'before Abraham was' ?* **The existence of deity.**

*How are we to classify this existence ?* **Utterly unique, in a way that no human and no angel could ever be classified.**